# How can I change command in ListBoxItem using ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the command using a `ToggleButton` (`DevMode`), for example:

- If `IsChecked` is `true` execute command (1)
- If `IsChecked` is `false` execute command (2)

Here is my code:

```
<DockPanel>
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ToggleButton x:Name="DevMode" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="30" Content="Developer Mode"/>
   </StackPanel>

   <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTile}">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Width="600" Height="600" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                             Rows="{Binding Path=GetRows}"
                             Columns="{Binding Path=GetCols}">
            </UniformGrid>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}">
               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                    <!--the command which I need to change-->
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.Command1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
                  </i:EventTrigger>
               </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: You can pass toggle button state into view-model and decide which command to run there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this without breaking MVVM is to use a style with a datatrigger like this:

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTile}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Width="600" Height="600" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Rows="{Binding Path=GetRows}" Columns="{Binding Path=GetCols}">
        </UniformGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandB}"/>
                                    <!--Your other command-->
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DevMode, Path=IsCecked}" Value="True">
                <!--Your trigger linked to the btn-->
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandA}"/>
                                        <!--Your command-->
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Comment: Do you really need two DataTriggers? While you may argue that `IsChecked` is a nullable bool, there should be a "default" ItemTemplate, set by a Style Setter, and one set by a Setter in a single DataTrigger.

Comment: changed it for your pleasure :)

Comment: @DenisSchaf While this is a valid solution to the issue, I think that this adds duplicated code as well as complexity. One issue I see here is that you reset the whole `Trigges` collection in the `DataTemplate` depending on the `IsChecked` property. If you have more than one trigger maybe even depending on another property this solution could escalate quickly.

Comment: @thatguy you could easly change the example above to only change the command to avoid dublicating. However i did not do that because i dont work with the eventtrigger thingies because i think they break part of the MVVM idea..kinda...sometimes...somehow...maybe.. so i could not test it and decided to change the entire template.
I agree that your suggestions is just as valid as this one, but this one keeps the view and the model further apart from each other

Comment: one could easily move the style inside of the image when a normal binding and not an interaction trigger would have been used. 
I guess in this case you could easly avoid the interaction trigger thingy by putting the image inside a button. The interaction trigger is always a workaround to give a control a function it was never supposed to serve like in this case transforming a image into a button, while the right way whould have been to just put the image inside of a button

Comment: concluding this with:
1.    put image into button
2.    give button style with normal command trigger and only change command binding
3.    stay conform with MVVM 4. Profit?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton` to your view model, but maybe give it a more meaningful name in the context of the view model than `IsChecked`.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="DevMode" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" Height="30" Content="Developer Mode" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

Since you want to execute two different commands or actions depending on a flag, you should create a separate command for that. Let's assume it is `MyCommand`. I think you would not even need to pass a command parameter, as the `SelectedTile` property is available in your view model anyway.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
```

In your view model, you can decide which method to excute based on the `IsChecked` state. In case you have a can execute delegate, you should adapt it as well.

```
private bool CanExecuteMyCommand(object item)
{
   return IsChecked && Command1.CanExecute(item) || !IsChecked && Command2.CanExecute(item);
}

private void ExecuteMyCommand(object item)
{
   if (IsChecked && Command1.CanExecute(item))
      Command1.Execute(item);
   else if (!IsChecked && Command2.CanExecute(item))
      Command2.Execute(item);
}
```

Please note that the code assumes, that you reuse `Command1` and `Command2` in other places, too. If not, you can delete them and just use their `Execute` and `CanExecute` delegates instead.

Comment: in my optinon you should do this in gui only and not in your viewmodel, however i agree that this is an edge case

Comment: @DenisSchaf As this approach complies with MVVM, using one or the other depends on the actual requirements or personal preference.